# Convergence of sum in $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Question:
> I need to prove that the sum $$ \left( \sum_{n = m + 1}^\infty y_n^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \to 0 $$
> where $\mathbf{y} \in \ell^2$ and $m$ can be chosen (i.e. I can let it tend toward infinity).

**My attempt:**

I know that $\mathbf{y} \in \ell^2$ and so I can set $$ \left( \sum_{n = 1}^\infty y_n^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = S.$$
By comparison, I know that $\left( \sum_{n = m + 1}^\infty y_n^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ must converge as well. Hence, for $m > K$, I can gaurantee that $|y_n|^2 <\epsilon$. Moreover, I can set $$ |y_n|^2 < \frac{\epsilon}{S}. $$
As such, for $m > K$, I have
$$ \left( \sum_{n = m + 1}^\infty y_n^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq \left( \sum_{n = m + 1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{S} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
I feel as if I'm one or two steps away here from showing what I need, but I can't seem to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What you need follows from a more general fact- if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ then $\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n \to 0$ as $m\to\infty$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Do you mind linking a proof of such a statement?

Comment: The proof is as follows. If $a_n, b_n$ converge to $a,b$ then $a_n + b_n$ converges to $a+b$. Now use that $\sum_1^n a_n$ converges you $\sum_1^\infty a_n$

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. Are you saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ converges to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a$ if $a_n \to a$?

Comment: No, I mean exactly what I said. What you said is very different From what I said.  if the sum even makes sense then what you wrote is that a constant converges to itself. True, but not helpful.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Since $\sum_{i= 1}^n a_i \to \sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_i$ then $  \sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_i - \sum_{i= 1}^n a_i  \to 0 \implies \sum_{i = n + 1}^\infty a_i \to 0$?

Comment: Essentially yes, but depending on your background I would need to see more to know that you fully understand the rigourous proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you showed in the end is that $\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty y_n^2 \le \infty$ which means you found a dead end.

Instead what you want follows from a standard result you normally see way before functional analysis and $\ell^2$ about convergent series:

> **Claim.** Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ exists. Then the ‘tail sum’ $T_m = \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n$ converges to zero as $m\to\infty$.

Convince yourself this is sufficient.

To prove the claim,

1. prove that the following decomposition is valid, where $S_m = \sum_{n=1}^m a_n$:
   $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = S_m + T_m $$
2. Notice that $S_m$ converges as $m\to\infty$, and therefore so does $T_m$.
3. As $S_m$ converges to the LHS which is a constant, sum rule for sequence limits gives the result.